# I cannot figure out how to prove $||x| - |y|| \leq |x - y|$

Tags: real-analysis

I had a quiz today in my Real Analysis course asking to prove:

for two vectors $x, y \in \Bbb{R^n}$, show that  $||x| - |y|| \leq |x - y|$. When does equality hold?

... I cannot figure it out for the life of me. It's really frustrating. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: that's the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality)

Comment: $|x|=|(x-y)+y|\leq|x-y|+|y|$ and so on ...

Comment: do you know the triangle inequality $|u|+|y|\le|u+y|$? take $u=x-y$

Comment: hint, if the vectors are colinear the equality is true

Comment: @J.W.Tanner How do you know to do that?

Comment: the triangle inequality involves the absolute values of three quantities, one of which is the sum of the other two; this inequality involves the absolute values of three quantities, one of which is the difference of the other two; if you define a new variable to be the sum of the other two, then one of the others becomes a difference

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The   [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality)
can be proved from the triangle inequality

$|u+y|\le|u|+|y|$ or $|u+x|\le|u|+|x|$

by taking $u=x-y$ and $u=y-x$:

$|x|\le|x-y|+|y|$ so $|x|-|y|\le|x-y|$ and  $|y|-|x|\le |y-x|$.

Therefore, $||x|-|y||\le|y-x|=|x-y|$.

Comment: This is just the top answer in the linked dupe.